# Skipping pyspark pip package when I want to insatlll other packages

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to install apcjckage named elephas by using its wheel file on windows, however. it has some requirments for pyspark and kers, I cant install pyspark on my anaconda due to firewall isssues on my PC. I have juts unzip pyspark and I am using it but , I want to know if there is anyway to skip the pyspark when installing elephas.

```
(base) C:\Users\Public>python -m pip install elephas-0.4.2-py3-none-any.whl
Processing c:\users\public\elephas-0.4.2-py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: hyperas in c:\users\kmob\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from elephas==0.4.2) (0.4.1)
Requirement already satisfied: keras in c:\users\kmob\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras-2.2.4-py3.7.egg (from elephas==0.4.2) (2.2.4)
Requirement already satisfied: flask in c:\users\kmob\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from elephas==0.4.2) (1.1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: cython in c:\users\kmob\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from elephas==0.4.2) (0.29.12)
Requirement already satisfied: tensorflow in c:\users\kmob\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from elephas==0.4.2) (1.14.0)
Collecting pyspark (from elephas==0.4.2)
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x00000000044F8358>, 'Connection to pypi.org timed out. (con
nect timeout=15)')': /simple/pyspark/
```

it cant download pyspark from the source since I have firewall, I have pyspark unzipped on my local machine and I can run it, is there anyway to skip the above pyspark installation check?